# default browser

Tags: google-chrome, browser

Some softwares are needed to open IE so that I can use their help/documentations.I set my default browser as google chrome.
 Currently when I click on help/Docs a page is automatically opened by google chrome but it doesn't show the information unless I copy & paste the path on IE again.
  How can I made that software using IE without changing my default Browser ,Any idea?

Comment: Are you talking about a file on your PC?  How are you getting to the "help/docs" page you are referring to?

Comment: nope,I've got a software,then on Help tab ->documentation it tries to open those help/docs pages ( the address is like: file:///C:/Program%20Files/OPNET/16.0.A/doc/modeler/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=Tutorials/basic_mdlr_tut_splash.html#1079840 )

Comment: What does the help content look like in Chrome?  Is it completely unusable?  Do you see an error message of some kind?

Comment: no error message,just a blank page divided by a vertical line.
but when I copy/Paste above link address in IE it shows information nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The software in question is almost certainly just opening an HTML help file without reference to a particular browser - the equivalent of double-clicking on the HTML file in Windows Explorer.  If that is in fact the case - unless the program has an option to change this behaviour - you're out of luck, since it would otherwise require changing the program.

Comment: The thing is as I set my default explorer Chrome,software would call chrome,but it seems information could not be fetch by chrome correctly.

Comment: Chrome doesn't yet have the kind of support enjoyed by IE and Firefox.  Same problem with Opera.  I'd use either Chrome or Opera exclusively if either of them worked properly with everything.  Note that this is more a problem with web sites and developers than with those browsers.

Answer (score 1):

With the push of a button you can [switch to an IE Tab inside Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd).

Comment: preferably I want not using add-ons softwares.

Comment: @user44509: I think perhaps you are being a bit picky.  You want Chrome as your default browser except for a single use-case, a buggy HTML help file.  Chrome, Windows, IE, these are not to blame, it is the third party software which is to blame.  Since you can't modify that, modifying Chrome seems like the easiest alternative.

Comment: Indeed, the add-on doesn't have any negative impact...

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a new program if it is a local file on your PC.  You can associate IE with html files and STILL have Chrome as your default browser.  Chrome will open links and IE will open files.  Just change your file association on .html files to IE.

`Find a file, right click, open with, choose program, select IE and check the box for "Always use the selected program..."`

Comment: that s an alternative,but I gotta go through a long path through program files to open it,
the thing I want is be able to open file in such software as normal routine when I click on it.

Comment: No, what I am saying is if you do this ONCE, it will open your html files through IE `PERMANENTLY`.  You only need to do this process one time to update it.

Comment: I tried this process and marked ''Always use the selected ..." but the problem still persists

Answer (score 0):

Try BrowserMaster: http://browsermaster.codeplex.com/releases/view/34262

It gets set as the default browser and allows you to choose which browser you want opened when you click or try to open something. I recommend setting the timer to 10 seconds.